# How do I use the dictionary plugin for Synapse on Linux?

Tags: linux, dictionary

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10. Synapse is installed, as is the dictionary app. When I want the definition of a word - "rebarbative", say - I type it directly into Synapse. The only result I see is "No results found."

Google searches have been unfruitful. Is there something special that I need to do? Thanks.

**Edit**: Synapse is no longer distributed by Ubuntu.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this ?

Comment: The Synapse software is in the Ubuntu repo. Please check by yourself and update your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install gnome dictionary

> sudo apt-get install gnome-dictionary

Then restart your session, the dictionary plugin should be activated automatically.

Comment: The newest version of gnome-dictionary is already installed.

Comment: And is the plugin activated in the Synapse settings ? If not what does it say ?

Comment: Yes, it's activated. That is, the Dictionary plugin is in the list, it's not grayed out, and it displays "enabled" when I select it.

Comment: Marking this as the solution, but note that Synapse is no longer available for Ubuntu.

Comment: Synapse is available in the 16.04 repos...